# Monotouch UITableView horizontal scrolling

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios

I'm working creating a control very similar to the "grid" that is showed in the Roambi demo application, this application includes a control similar in appearance to a grid (or an Excel sheet with data and without the editing feature), I think it is based on a TableView with custom cells, but I don't know how to get an horizontal scrolling behavior on that table to see my custom cells which are width (cause they include labels which represent data of several columns).
I don't know if you can help me with the best approach to take to begin with the development of this control, precisely the scrolling issue (use one tableview per column, or just one, include an additional scrollview, etc) , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Having one TableView for each column won't be much fun, because you would have to sync the scroll positions between the columns. 
So I would try to get away with the horizontally scrolled TableView. But if you need to be sure that the grid works even if it's very wide, I would think of addding/removing/reusing the cell views while scrolling like TableView itself does it for the vertical part. 
If you implement dynamic views anyway, it wouldn't be much more effort to place the cells in a scroll view and do the adding/removing for the entire two dimensions.